# What is the charset of connection from Hibernate to MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I connect to MySQL DB from Java using Jpa/Hibernate library. MySQL document says 'you must change the character settings for each connection to the server, if you don't use defaults'.

How do I know which Charset the underlying connection is using and how to change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `characterEncoding` and `CharSet` properties for changing charset used by hibernate.

Example: To set charset to utf-8:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

Comment: I try to first confirm the character set in use, in mysql client this command shows the current setting in use 
>show variables like '%character%'
By the way i use org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource for datasource and org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter for jpaVendorAdapter to create entity manager.